# Trying to insert char ] (spanish layout keyboard) do ZoomIN

Tags: visual-studio-code, key-bindings

I do not know when this happened, but now every time I run the key combination Ctrl + Máyus +] (Spanish Distribution), I can insert the character `]`, and my interface does zoomIn action

My json of keybindings is as follows:

```
// Place your key bindings in this file to overwrite the defaults
[
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If restarting VSCode without any plugins activated ("safe mode") does not solve the issue, that means the problem lies within VSCode itself.

Check if this is releated to [Microsoft/vscode issue 51303](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/51303)

> There is a command "`Zoom in`" (`workbench.action.zoomIn`) in keyboard shortcuts...
>   actually, but default, there are 3 of them, with different keybindings.
>
> And when you remove all three of them - and then trying to reset to default, it resets the keybindings one after another.

Answer (score 1):

**Solved**

The error was related to an extension. Specifically EasyZoom, I used it to zoom with Ctrl + mousewheel, but it seems to give problems. What happens is that until then I had not had problems.

I have solved it by deleting that extension. Thank you.

For the next one to come with an incident like this Follow these steps.

Disable all extensions.

Prove that your problem has disappeared.

Go enabling the extensions one by one, and check which is the extension that fails.

This happens because the extensions add functionality to the new Visual Studio Code external to the application, and the programmer of the extension can make mistakes or overwrite some configuration.

It is also not good to have too many extensions, or if you should have them, be sure to set them well configured, in regard to keyboard shortcuts